# trying to port Tika 1.0 to Android in Eclipse: error messages refercing pom.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, apache-tika

I am trying to port Tika 1.0 core and parsers source code to Android in Eclipse and having problems. Here's what I did:

- Downloaded Tika 1.0 source
- Opened core and parsers sub-projects in Eclipse using Maven plugin
- Exported both into their respective JARs
- Copied the JAR files into the libs folder of a "wrapper" Android project that I want to use to test tika's capabilities on a 4.0 device
- Cleaned and rebuilt the project

When I tried to launch it on a device, I got this error:

```
Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: pom.xml
Origin 1: C:\...\libs\tika-core.jar
Origin 2: C:\...\libs\tika-parsers.jar
```

The two JARs do contain pom.xml files but they are different.

My goal is to be able to step through tika's code on the device. So what do I need to do to be able to launch on Android?

Thx

Comment: If you want Tika to be able to actually parse your files, you'll need to include all the parser dependencies too. This is likely to cause you issues though, firstly with xml and graphics based stuff (they're different on android), and secondly with the maximum library size (Android sulks if you try to convert much code)

Comment: I am aware of the parser incompatibilities, but thanks anyway. I will be happy if I can get a small subset of them to work.